# How to do URL rewriting for the URL to hide filename.aspx and querystring?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

https://mysite.com/Admin/Dashboard/DashboardReport.aspx - this is my actual URL i want to hide the filename.aspx with if any querystring values. how?

also i have tried FriendlyURL in URL rewriting in IIS.
it doesn't take effect.

Pls give me a quick reply.

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there about how to Either ReWrite or Redirect a URL.  But in the case where somebody may actually visit the hard-path, you need to do both.  I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use rewrite rules and the rewrite module.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: Nice article But couldn't get my Pattern value for my URL https://mysite.com/Admin/Dashboard/DashboardReport.aspx to https://mysite.com/Admin/Dashboard/

Comment: You could rename DashboardReport.aspx to index.aspx and IIS will run that with the URL you are wanting.  I'm not positive on this next part, but you could try putting a web.config in the subdirectory and specify a default document.  <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument enabled="true">
         <files>
            <add value="home.html" />
         </files>
      </defaultDocument>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: Actually, you're probably going to want to go with URL routing which can be enabled for webforms.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx

Comment: Confirm me if i go to mysite.com/Admin/Dashboard/2.aspx what will be rewritten URL to the user... sry i'm new to this topic

Comment: I have added a Blank URL rewrite in my IIS as follows 1. Pattern as /*.aspx     2. using - Regular Expressions   3. Action type as Rewrite      4. Action Properties as https://mysite.com/Admin/ and i saved these settings and refreshed it... it shows me 404 file not found error.. why :(

Answer (score 1):

URL Rewriting is somewhat ambiguous.  Are you rewriting what the user sees?  Or what the server sees?  It's better to believe that you are not able to alter what the URL displays to the website consumer.

However, the trick is to send them to a broken, not-real URL... then ReWrite the URL for YOU, so you know what that not-real URL means.  For example:

Imagine you have a Real URL like so:

`http://www.example.com/folder/subfolder/page.ext?param=value`

But you want to "Rewrite" the URL to look like so:

`http://www.example.com/subfolder/value`

If they are on the page `page.ext...`, you cannot change what they see in their URL bar.  But, you can Redirect Them to a fake path `/subfolder/value` like so:

```
<rule name="subFolder Value Redirect">
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/folder/([^/]+)/page\.ext\?param=([^&]+)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="/{C:1}/{C:2}" />
</rule>
```

Above, I am not doing a "url match" because I am depending solely on a Condition.  My only Condition is that the Request_URI looks exactly like I expect.  Some folder, some subfolder name, page.ext, and a querystring with param=SomeValue.  I use `()` parenthesis to dynamically capture the Subfolder Name and the param Value.

Note: {C:0} means the "0th" Capture Group of the Conditions.  Capture 0 is the Entire Result of the regex `^/folder/([^/]+)/page\.ext\?param=([^&]+)$`.  Capture 1 is the First Capture Group, the Subfolder Name.  Capture 2 is the second Capture Group, the param Value.

`^` at the beginning of a regex means "starting from the beginning".  Sometimes you don't want to start at the beginning and that wouldn't be there.

`$` at the end of a regex means "ending at the end".  Sometimes you don't want to end at the end and that wouldn't be there.

The Character Class `[^...]` means to capture any character that is not `...`.  In this case, capture anything that is not a Slash, or anything that is not an Ampersand.

The repetition operator `[...]+` Plus-Symbol means to capture the preceding rule at least once, but up to many times.

`.` is a special character which means "anything".  But we mean it as in the dot of an extension `page.ext`.  So you escape it like `\.`

`{REQUEST_URI}`  means to compare your pattern against the entire URL after the Domain/Port.  So in the URL `http://www.example.com:1234/subfolder...` The /subfolder and all following contents are in the {REQUEST_URI} **EXCEPT** hashtag routing.  So if you have an Anchor or Angular UI Route, those stay with the browser only, and will always be at the end of any redirect, but the server will never see them, so you can't parse off of hashtags.

`action type="Redirect"` just means this action is to redirect the user to a given URL.

`url="/{C:1}/{C:2}"` is the URL relative to the domain, since it doesn't start with a protocol.  This will redirect to /subFolder/value, because Condition capture 1 and Condition capture 2 in our pattern capture those two values.

After inserting this rule, a user will be redirected to a broken janked up URL that looks like a State-Representative URL (RESTful). **Yaay!!**

### URL Rewriting

The rewrite is for you (the server), not for the customer.  But now that they are redirected to a nice pretty broken URL, you can find the context of that URL and tell your server what it REALLY means by rewriting it for the server.

```
<rule name="subFolder Value Rewrite">
  <conditions><add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" /></conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder/{C:1}/page.ext?param={C:2}" />
</rule>
```

This is pretty much the inverse of the prior rule.  This finds a pattern where there is a path "subFolder" name, slash, and a value made up of letters and numbers.  It also, once again, describes the Begginning `^` and End `$`, because we don't expect unexpected weird things.  So, this will catch a URL like:

`http://www.example.com/subFolder/1234abcDE`

But will not catch

`http://www.example.com/lol/somethingelse/15?blah=kthx`

The rewrite URL then evaluates back to a true real URL that maps to a path for processing for a file that really exists.  And, keep in mind, that "rewrite" means it takes the "incorrect" fake value that the user sees, and rewrites it back to an ugly "correct" value for the server.  Not the other way around.