# How do i hide page name in web.config with xml?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I am wondering if there's a way to hide a page name on a website (in the browser URL) but still show the get request using the IIS web.config file?

imagine the site name is 
`www.website.com`

with a page of (file extension is already hidden)
`www.website.com/page.php`

a get request of 
`www.website.com/page.php?user=text`
where "text" is dynamic

and I want it to appear as 
`www.website.com/text`

is this something that is possible?

I noticed a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830915/how-to-do-url-rewriting-for-the-url-to-hide-filename-aspx-and-querystring), but the method did not seem to work even after changing the asp to XML.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
Here is the xml code I am attempting to use (this specific code does not work)

```
<rule name="subFolderValueRedirect" enabled="true">
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/page\.php?user=([^/]+)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="/{C:2}" />
</rule>
<rule name="fileValueRewrite" enabled="true">
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/([^/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" /></conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/page.php?user={C:2}" />
</rule>
```

EDIT 2:
Here is what my IIS is spitting out; but it throws an error 500 for me

Inbound Rules -

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^page$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^user=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="page?user={R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

Outbound Rules

```
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="OutboundRewriteUserFriendlyURL1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^(.*/)page\?user=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}{R:2}/" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
```

Comment: Is there any particular framework/language you are using?

Comment: what do you mean?
the site is using php which is running on iis
and the web.config file uses xml

Comment: It's been a while since I've interacted with IIS but this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43352452/3783243 looks correct. Could you show what you tried and what happened? Also which IIS version you are using would also probably be useful

Comment: This is the same link I posted, this method didn't work. After having it fail I looked the {C:#} method up and it appears as though it is used by asp (based on my research) and doesn't work with xml but when i change it to {R:#} i get an error 500. I am using IIS version 10.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try below url rewrite rules.

You could firstly redirect the url from `www.website.com/page.php?user=text` to `www.website.com/text`, then you could rewrite the `www.website.com/text` to `/page.php?user=text`.

Rule as below:

```
            <rule name="Re1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="page.php" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="user=([^/]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:9082/text" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RE2">
                <match url="([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/page.php?user={R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: this will not work correctly, the text part in "user=text" is dynamic based on a database selection

Comment: You mean the text will also changed in in the  query string. Does this query string will contain multiple keys?

Comment: Multiple keys? I dont know. The easiest way to explain it is think of facebook profiles, behind that url of for example facebook.com/username is facebook.com/profile.php?id=stringofnumbers | im trying to make it so when i click on a users profile on my site, it hides the page name and such and just shows the text after the equal sign (being the username of said person)